# Yii redirect from controller action after ajax call not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii

I use the following buttons in my view file (don't pay attention to second one, but I just wanted to show you why I'm not using a normal form submit):

```
    <?php echo CHtml::Button('Search Symptom(s)', array('id'=>'search'));  ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::Button('Add Another Symptom to Search', array('id'=>'addSymptom'));  ?>
```

When the user clicks the buttons this javascript runs (it's inside a document.ready function)

```
$('#search').click(function()
        {   
            //create new symptom in javascript
            var newSymptom = 
            {
                symptomCode: $('#symptomToBeSearchedCode').val(),
                dateSymptomFirstSeen: $('#dateSymptomSeen').val(),
                symptomTitle: $('#symptomToBeSearchedTitle').val()
            };
            //pass new symptom into symptomsList array
            symptomsList.push(newSymptom);
            //make ajax call to server
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: '/mysymptomsbook/index.php?r=symptomhistory/search',
                data:{symptomsList: symptomsList} ,
                dataType:'html'
            });
        });
```

symptomsList is an array with JS objects

This is the code in my controller action:

```
 if(isset($_POST['symptomsList']))
    {   
        foreach($_POST['symptomsList'] as $symptom)
        {
            //populate symptom search model attributes with user id, current date, and form input
            $newSymptom = new Symptomhistory;
            $newSymptom->setAttributes(array(
                                'user_id'=>Yii::app()->user->id,
                                'dateSearched'=>date('Y-m-d'),
                                'symptomCode'=>$symptom['symptomCode'],
                                'dateSymptomFirstSeen'=>$symptom['dateSymptomFirstSeen'],
                                'symptomTitle'=>$symptom['symptomTitle'],
                                 ));
            //save search history
            $newSymptom->save();
            //add into the searched for symptoms code the latest code
            array_push($symptomCodes, strval($symptom['symptomCode']));
        }

        $this->redirect(array('disease/index'));
    }
```

I was planning on using redirect to send the $symptomCodes array to the other controlleraction (DiseasesController and actionIndex), but even without passing anything the redirect doesn't work. The models get saved to my database normally.

Anyone have any idea what is wrong? I'm thinking it has to do with Ajax since it's waiting for a response, but I want my controller to redirect instead. Any help as always, is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problem, recommend you to look at this topic at official forum:
[redirect not working when called via Ajax-Request](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/26559-redirect-not-working-when-called-via-ajax-request/)

See the last answer in topic.